# Elasticsearch - what to do if fields have the same name but multiple mapping

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I use Elasticsearch for storing data sent from multiple sources outside of my system, i.e. I'm not controlling the incoming data - I just receive json document and store it. I have no logstash with its filters in the middle, only ES and Kibana. Each data source sent its own data type and all of them are stored in the same index (per tenant) but in different types. However since I cannot control the data that is sent to me, it is possible to receive documents of different types with the field having the same name and different structure.
**For example**, assume that I have type1 and type2 with field FLD, which is an object in both cases but the structure of this object is not the same. Specifically FLD.name is a string field in type1 but an object in type2. And in this case, when type1 data arrives it is stored successfully but when type2 data arrives, it is rejected:

> failed to put mappings on indices [[myindex]], type [type2]
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapper for [FLD] conflicts with existing mapping in other types[Can't merge a non object mapping [FLD.name] with an object mapping [FLD.name]]

ES documentation clearly declare that fields with the same name in the same index in different mapping types mapped to the same field internally and must have the same mapping ([see here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#field-conflicts)).

**My question** is what can I do in this case? I'd prefer to keep all the types in the same index. Is it possible to add a unique-per-type suffix to field names or something like this? Any other solution? I'm a newbie in Elasticsearch so maybe I'm missing something simple... Thanks in advance.

Comment: I really doubt if there is any way out, except for using different name.. because this feature was something implemented by elastic in 2.0, and it was a pretty big change from their end

Comment: If I want to use different name - how I'm doing it technically? Is there any "filter" that modifies the name based on certain pattern? Since fields are dynamic, I cannot do it in advance, before data arrives. What feature should I look for in their documentation? Another option I thought about is to redesign the way data is stored: use current type as index (all the data in each index will be mapped the same way) and make tenant id one of the fields added somehow to the document. Though it makes indices bigger and multi-tenancy support more challenging.

Comment: No there is no filter that can mosify the name of a field based on any pattern... I will suggest you to rethink about how the data need to be stored.. Storing the type as an index is also not recommended..

Comment: Any luck with this ? Please share what you did.

Comment: Eventually the original problem was solved by saving different types in different indices. Not the brilliant idea but we couldn't think about something better. Note that we have multiple but limited number of sources so number of indices grows reasonably. In addition we added pre-index-enricher service that interfering to the data-in flow just before actual indexing of the document. We add some synthetic fields there. However if your fields list is known list (but not types), you can use it for renaming. It wasn't our case though (fields list could change) so we didn't use it for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do index arbitrary JSON without pre-processing before it's indexed - not even [Dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/dynamic-templates.html) are flexible enough.

You can flatten nested objects into key-value pairs and use a [Nested datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/nested.html), [Multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/multi-fields.html), and [`ignore_malformed`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/ignore-malformed.html) to index arbitrary JSON (even with type conflicts) as described [here](https://dev.to/chrismwendt/indexing-arbitrary-json-into-elasticsearch-28m7). Unfortunately, Elasticsearch can still throw an exception at query time if you try to, for example, match a string to `kv_pairs.value.long`, so you'll have choose appropriate fields based on format of the value.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best practice I suppose, but you can store the field content as a `String` and make the deserialization manually after retrieve the information.

So, imagine a class like:

```
class Person {
    private final Object name;
}
```

That can receive a `List` of `String` or a List of any other `Object`, just for example

So, instead of serialize the Person to a `String` and save it, you can serialize to a `String` **and** save the content on another class, like:

```
String personContent new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(person);
RequestDto dto = new RequestDto(personContent);
String dtoContent new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(dto);
```

And save the `dtoContent`:

```
IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest("persons")
request.source(dtoContent, XContentType.JSON);
IndexResponse response = client.index(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

The `RequestDto` will be a simple class with a `String` field:

```
class RequestDto {
    private String content;
}
```

I'm not a expert on ElasticSearch, but probably you will loose a lot of features from the ElasticSearch by passing his validations doing that.