# Solr mapping types sharing field name but different datatype

Tags: solr, lucene, mapping

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513132/elasticsearch-what-to-do-if-fields-have-the-same-name-but-multiple-mapping), ES mapping, containing multiple types which share some field name, must be of the same data type as well.

Example:

```
{ "eventName": "DescribePlacementGroups", "eventSource": "ec2.amazonaws.com"}
{ "eventName": "DescribeAccountAttributes", "eventSource": "1.2.3.4"}
```

In ES, indexing the above documents to the same index, will result in mapping exception as the *eventSource* field, shared among both types was indexed first as a string, the second time, tried to index it as IP type.

Will it be the case in Solr as well? may be a Lucene limitation?

Comment: So it is actually a Lucene limitation...?

Comment: No, you can put different field types into the same field in Lucene, but neither ES nor Solr allow it (likely because how you should analyze queries, sort, etc. becomes ambiguous).

Comment: Really, they are probably already doing some of this under the hood, actually, but in a controlled, predictable way. If you mix up a bunch of arbitrary, unrelated data types in the same field, you'll be unable to search and sort that field in a sane way. But Lucene will definitely give you the power to shoot yourself in the foot if you want to.

Comment: Exactly what are you going to use the field for? Defining it as a type that allows both formats seems like the best choice (i.e. a string field in this case)

Comment: My specific use-case was AWS CloudTrail logs, you have gazzilion `eventNames` (I use eventName as ES type mapping). the effort of tracking all fields' types is huge, trying to solve in a generic fashion